# Program triggering a breakpoint

Tags: c++, templates, arraylist

Hey I'm having trouble figuring out what is causing my program to trigger a breakpoint. For school I had to write a class using templates that mimics a java array list, but in c++. My code seems to work when I only use the push method that I have written more than twice in a test. If I try pushing more than two values onto the arraylist, it starts triggering breakpoints.

Here's my code:
HeaderFile:

Arraylist.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template<class t>
class ArrayList {

public:
    ArrayList();
    void push_back(t m);
    void erase(t m);
    int size();
    string toString();
    t& operator[](unsigned int i);
private:
    int currentIndex;
    int sizeOfArray;
    t *p;
    int currentindex;

};
```

ArrayList.cpp

```
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class t>
ArrayList<t>::ArrayList() {
    p = new t[1];
    sizeOfArray = 1;
    currentIndex = 0;
    p[currentIndex] = 0;
    currentIndex++;

}

template<class t>
int ArrayList<t>::size() {
    return sizeOfArray;
}

template<class t>
void ArrayList<t>::erase(t m) {
    int location = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++) {
        if (p[i] == m) {
            location = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = location; i < currentIndex - 1; i++) {
        p[i] = p[i + 1];
    }
    currentIndex--;
}

template<class t>
void ArrayList<t>::push_back(t m) {
    if (currentIndex < sizeOfArray-1) {
        t *temp = new t[sizeOfArray + 1];
        sizeOfArray++;

        for(int i=0;i<sizeOfArray-1;i++){
        temp[i] = p[i];
        }
    temp[currentIndex] = m;
    currentIndex++;
    sizeOfArray++;

    delete [] p;
    t *p = new t[sizeOfArray];

    p = temp;

    delete [] temp;
}
    else {
        p[currentIndex] = m;
        currentIndex++;

    }
}

template<class t>
t& ArrayList<t>::operator[](unsigned int i) {
    return p[i];
}

template<class t>
string ArrayList<t>::toString() {
    string output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++) {
        output += to_string(p[i]);

    }
    return output;
}
```

Source.cpp (just using it as a scratchpad for testing)

```
#include "ArrayList.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ArrayList<double> list = ArrayList<double>();
    list.push_back(1.0);
    list.push_back(2.0);
    list.push_back(3.0);
    //list.push_back(4.0);

    cout << list.toString();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that the problem has something to do with me somehow going out of bounds with one of my array's, but I can't seem to figure it out (perhaps I've just been staring at this assignment for to long). Any help, or suggestions would be much appreciated as always.

Comment: `sizeof(p)` does not give you the length of the array. You have to store that somewhere. Also, delete the old array. Extending the array by only one element will not perform well (doubling the size is common). Why is there an initial zero in the list? Also, the second copy from the temporary array to `p` is not necessary. Just swap the pointers.

Comment: For some reason it's a requirement from our teacher to only increase the size by one, and he wants us to initialize the first element to be zero. Just added the bits about deleting the array, and swapping the pointers, thank you. The primary issue I was having still persists though.

Comment: The primary reason I mentioned was `sizeof(p)` not returning the array length.

Comment: ahhhh yea, I realize that now, the sizeof() method returns the size in bytes, not the actual array length correct? just trying to make sure i understand why it isn't working. Sorry I'm new to the c++ language.

Comment: Yes, but it does not work for arrays. It will return the size of the pointer, which has nothing to do with the pointed-to size.

Comment: Slight niggle: `sizeof` will work for a static array, but won't with a dynamic array or after the static array has been decayed to a pointer.

Comment: Just updated my code, I believe I'm now correctly keeping track of the size of the array, but my issue still persists.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: use your debugger!!!!!  Your debugger will tell you *WHERE* you're crashing ("triggering a breakpoint" ;)); it can help you figure out *WHY* you're crashing.  Learning to use your debugger is *EVERY* bit as important as learning to use your compiler.

Comment: I have been using the debugger, I should have probably shared this info from the start, It gets stuck on the second push statement. When I step through my code, it gets stuck on the delete [] p; statement. Stepping though it brings me to the void _CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept function in the delete_scalar.cpp file, which is where the program is tripping up.